# How can i rotate a vector light source?

Tags: c#, monogame

I have a 3d Vector, lets say (-0.7f, -1, -0.5f). I want this to be the forward direction of the light source and then have it rotate/spin to create a sunlight effect around an object. I'm attempting to do this in monogame with C# but I am blanking right now and can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd think you would multiply it by a rotation matrix.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I can do that, but I don't know how to calculate the rotation matrix in monogame with the forward vector I defined.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MonoGame, but I think you can multiply the light by the matrix for the position transform of the object, and then apply the light's own rotation/position matrix after that, thus becoming a child of the main object's position. I'm not 100% sure though as it has been a long time since I've studied matrices. If you do find a solution based on this, please don't forget to answer your own question here so that it might help someone else. :)

Comment: I normally would search for a Matrix.LookAt() method which transforms a position/target to a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting a light vector and transforming that light vector from a matrix. This works fine for a light source rotation around a "planet" on a tilted axis. This can also be used to have an object rotate in the same way by multiplying the negative lightDirection by the distance (this would only rotate around the origin of 0,0 unless you account for the positional offset)

```
Vector3 lightVector = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f);

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    roll += 0.005f;

    lightDirection = Vector3.Transform(lightVector, Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0, (90-45)*3.14f/180, roll));
    lightDirection.Normalize();
}
```